# Adding views to already created Layout

Tags: android

In my onResume() Method I would like to add some Views to my LinearLayout.  I have stored the LinearLayout as a global variable and need to inflate another View and add it to it but I keep getting various exceptions.

Can this be done and if so, how?

I have a lot of code but this is what it looks like so far:

```
LinearLayout ll; //Global Variable storing linear layout

onResume(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    View test = inflater.inflate(R.layout.method_choice_title, (ViewGroup) ll);
    test.setClickable(false);
    linLayout.addView(test);
 }
```

LogCat -> IllegalStateException.  Specified child already has a parent.  You must call removeView() first.....

Comment: Please post your code and LogCat

Answer (score 2):

Once you want to add `test` to `ll` you do not need `linLayout`.
Also you must pass `false` as last parameter in `inflate` method in order to later add `test` to `ll`.

Change onResume to this:

```
LinearLayout ll; //Global Variable storing linear layout
onResume(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View test = inflater.inflate(R.layout.method_choice_title, ll, false);
    test.setClickable(false);
    ll.addView(test);
}
```

Comment: You should explain the false argument.